# Add a specific value from a log line to another log line in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk

Is it possible to transfer a certain value of a log line to another log line inside of the Logstash config?

I need the value **RoundTripDuration** of line CLIENT in the line of REQUEST

Current state:

```
CLIENT : Session: 97B31BBDBB793E62107178C911683FB4, RoundtripDuration: 185ms, ClientUpdate: 3 ms
REQUEST: Session: 97B31BBDBB793E62107178C911683FB4, Total: 163ms, Invoke: 126ms (#{d.d_9.GenericDialogUI}
```

Target state:

```
CLIENT : Session: 97B31BBDBB793E62107178C911683FB4, RoundtripDuration: 185ms, ClientUpdate: 3 ms
REQUEST: Session: 97B31BBDBB793E62107178C911683FB4, Total: 163ms, Invoke: 126ms (#{d.d_9.GenericDialogUI}, RoundtripDuration: 185ms
```

Comment: you could use the multiline codec (or aggregate filter) on your input so that the two lines (CLIENT & REQUEST) are merged in one event.

Comment: Or maybe the [memcached filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-memcached.html) to store/read the value? Still I don't think what you want is a well-supported use case in logstash.